# Searching for occurrences of , before specific word

Tags: grep

I have a csv file in which I have to find the number of lines with the specific word "Happy" at the 6th position ie. after 5 commas.

So i am writing this:

```
grep -P -c  ",\{5,\}"'Happy' file.csv
```

but it is returning 0.

The content of file is:

> 123,abc,def,ghi,e444,Happy,224,e44

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grep -E '^([^,]*,){5}Happy' <in >out
```

That will find *`Happy`* only if it is immediately adjacent to the 5th comma. If you want to find it anywhere within the 6th field, then add a little breathing room:

```
grep -E '^([^,]*,){5}[^,]*Happy' <in >out
```

If you want just a count of the lines that match use the `-c` option:

```
grep -cE '^([^,]*,){5}[^,]*Happy' <in >out
```

I'm very familiar with regular expressions, but even if I wasn't, I think I would still choose re syntax over other kinds. Once you get the hang of some baselines the rest falls together. Regular expressions describe input by combining a very few basic building blocks in any number of ways.

- `*` *Kleene Star*

  - indicates the immediately previous expression occurs 0 or more times
- `[` bracket expression `]`

  - indicates an occurrence of any of a *(possibly `^` negated)* set of contained characters
- `{` min `,` max `}` repetition

  - specifies an occurrence count for the immediately previous expression
  - the extended regexp `?` metacharacter is just shorthand for `{0,1}`.
- `(` sub expression `)`

  - gathers any contained expressions into a single expression.
- `.` character

  - matches any single character
- `^|$`

  - indicate either a `^` head-of-line anchor for the following expression, or an `|` alternation between expressions, or a `$` tail-of-line anchor

Those are the basics. POSIX `-E`xtended regular expression syntax also includes the *Kleene* *`+`* - which is identical to the *`*`* in every way except that it requires *at least one* match for the previous expression. There are also all kinds of possible subtleties to do with `[` bracket expressions `]` - especially to do with inner `[(:|.|=)` character classes `(=|.|:)]` and how they match repetitions. And most implementations actually *extend* the extended re syntax at least to handle basic regexp `\[num]` back-references to an earlier `(` sub expression `)`.

But given just the basics, any one of the above expressions or any other single character is an expression unto itself, and they all combine into the overall expression to describe the match you desire.

Put all that together and the `grep` expression above breaks down as follows:

- `^([^,]*,){5}Happy`

  - Beginning at the left-most position, a matched line must contain no more or less than 5 sequences of 0 or more not-comma characters each of which is followed immediately by a comma character and all of which is immediately followed by the string *`Happy`*.

Comment: I have used grep -cE '^([^,]*,){5}[^,]*Happy' <in >out but somehow i am getting 1 result less

Comment: it won't work if 233,33,445,,323,Happy....

Comment: @Aquarius24: `echo 233,33,445,,323,Happy | grep -cE '^([^,]*,){5}Happy'` prints `1`

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
grep '^[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,Happy' file.txt
```

Assuming 5 commas from the start of the line, if from anywhere in the line just remove initial `^`.

Your pattern is simply looking for lines having five or more commas sucessively.

Comment: I have used grep '*,*,*,*,*,Happy' file.txt | wc -l but it is fetching me 0 results

Answer (score 2):

I think that using `awk` makes for a simpler and easier command when dealing with CSV files. It has natural support for the concept of fields which makes life a lot easier.

```
awk -F, '$6 == "Happy" { count++ } END { print count }' file.csv
```

The command breaks down as follows:

```
awk             -  The command to run
-F,             -  Use a comma as the field separator
$6 == "Happy"   -  Only match lines where the sixth field equals "Happy"
{ count++ }     -  For each line matched, add one to the "count" variable
END             -  When all that is done...
{ print count } -  ...print the value of "count"
file.csv        -  The file to read from
```

Comment: Added some detail and also indicated that it's mostly opinion. If you don't think my command looks simpler than the `grep` examples, then `grep` is probably your friend!

Comment: Does it make sense now?

Comment: No, he's looking to count 'the number of lines with the specific word "Happy" at the 6th position'. That's why he has the `-c` switch in the grep example and why he mentions it returning "0".